# LINQ sentence, check if remain elements

Tags: c#, linq

We're new in LINQ and we want to know if the are any method to check if there are elements remaining in the sentence like the ResultSet.next() from Java.

In Java the resultSet return true if there are elements remaining and false if not. We want to know if the is a method like that in LINQ.

```
public List<Product> FindProductsByKeyword(string productName, Category category, int page, int size)
    {

        DbSet<Product> products = Context.Set<Product>();

        List<Product> result;
        if (category == null)
        {
            result = (from p in products
                      where p.productName.Contains(productName) //, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                      orderby p.productName descending
                      select p).Skip(page).Take(size).Include("Category").ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            result = (from p in products
                      where p.productName.Contains(productName)
                      && p.categoryId == category.id
                      orderby p.productName descending
                      select p).Skip(page).Take(size).ToList();
        }


        return result;
    }
```

This our code( I dont know if this will help) we take elements with a number of Size but we dont know if there are more elements.

Comment: "in the sentence"? What is the resultSet in your sample C# code? `result` only has `size` elements in it at most and you can see you many are in `result` by looking at `result.Count`. You no longer have any access to elements beyond that in the database after you did the `Take`.

Comment: I'm guessing that Java's `ResultSet` acts a lot like a .NET `DataReader`; that is that you need to read from it until the end to get the data - it acts somewhat like a forward-only, read-only cursor. A LINQ query's semantics are closer to the set operations common in a relational database. The data is delivered is eventually delivered in an IEnumerable, but it is semantically all there once the query is *materialized* (for example, by calling `ToList()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the terminating method `ToList()` initiates a DB query and parses the returned table as a simple in-memory `List<T>` (same as `ArrayList<T>` in Java).

If you want to check if there are any entries in the result, you can just check the list's `Count` property:

```
if (result.Count > 0)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Or use LINQ's `Any()` extension method, which is a bit more readable in this context:

```
if (result.Any())
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you returned an Enumerable, then you could use `Enumerable.MoveNext()`

For example:

```
var p = products.AsEnumerable();

var i = p.GetEnumerator();

while( i.MoveNext())
    i.Current.productfieldname.Dump() // LinqPad .Dump() shows value
```